# How to install 32-bit version of libstdc++.so.6 on a 64 bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, php, 32-bit, extension, shared-library

I need to install the 32-bit version of libstdc++.so.6 on a 64 bit Ubuntu 8.04.2 server.

when i tried `apt-get install ia32-libs`, it says

```
root@devserver:~/downloads# apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
```

But when i tried to enable a PHP extension (libpdf_php.so), which uses this runtime library following error is logged in php error log.

```
root@devserver:~/downloads# cat /var/log/apache2/php_error.log
[01-Nov-2011 16:54:09] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613/libpdf_php.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/libpdf_php.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0
root@devserver:~/downloads#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think you need a 32-bit version of libstdc++.so.6?

64-bit Ubuntu runs 64-bit Apache which runs 64-bit PHP which it seems can't load 32-bit `libpdf_php.so`, which it tells you in the error message.

It's unlikely that installing ia32-libs will solve the problem - I would say you need 64-bit version of libpdf_php.so

It looks like [pdflib's website](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/) has a separate download for x86-64 architecture - I downloaded the archive and the .so file inside it is definitely 64-bit.

Answer (score 37):

You could've used `apt-get install lib32stdc++6`.

Comment: This answered the question in the title (How to install 32-bit version of libstdc++.so.6 on a 64 bit machine) to me.

Comment: Hi, When I run `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6` its give me o/p like :
 `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lib32stdc++6`
 But, when I run `ls /usr/lib32` Its not exist.
 Please let me know where I am wrong.
 Thanks.

Comment: This helped me get bison running for an Android source build on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I had to add the `:i386` after the package name (I actually wanted the 32 bit version of libstdc++.so.5: `apt-get install libstdc++5:i386`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with libstdc++, it's with libpdf_php.so.  You need to download the 32-bit version of that library.